# Black and white balls and a jar

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A jar contains $5$ white balls and $8$ black balls. We select one ball at a time without replacing it until there are balls of only one color.

What is the probability that the jar contains only white balls after the process stops?

---

My thinking is that we choose $5-k$ white balls and $8$ black balls, where $k=1,2,3,4,5$, so as there are $k$ white balls left in the jar.

So, the probability should be:

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{\binom{5}{5-k}}{\binom{13}{13-k}}=\sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{\binom{5}{k}}{\binom{13}{k}}=\frac{5}{9}\simeq0.5555$$

However, this answer is false since the correct one is $0.3845$

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Note that an answer greater than $\frac12$ is unreasonable: it is clearly more likely that the jar will contain only black balls than that it will contain only white balls, since there are more black balls to start with. (If you multiply $0.3845$ by $13$, you may be able to guess what the exact correct answer is.)

Comment: Yes, I understand why it should be less than $\frac{1}{2}$. (This operation yields $4.9985\simeq5$, but the problem here is not the result but rather how we derive this result.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Each of the $13$ balls has an equal chance of being the last ball removed from the jar.

Comment: This statement is true, but still I don't see how that would be helpful... (The difficulty for me in this exercise is probably that I've never encountered another one where we don't select a fixed number of balls, cards etc.)

Comment: @JimVerr: If the jar ends up containing only white balls, what color was the last ball that was removed? What if it ends up containing only black balls?

Comment: It could be either color as long as we haven't already selected $4$ white balls, since there are five cases overall: we select $8$ balls ($8$ black - $0$ white), $9$ balls ($8$ black - $1$ white), ..., $12$ balls ($8$ black - $4$ white).

Comment: @JimVerr: No, if you end up with only white balls, the last ball removed <em>must</em> have been black. If it were white, the jar would already have contained only white balls, so you wouldn't have removed another ball.